# How would you restructure this strangely coded layout to be 3 col flex layout?

Tags: html, css

I am editing a site to be 3 columns.

Here is example page, currently 2 columns:

https://courses.guitar-dreams.com/lessons/an-introduction-to-triads-and-their-inversions/

So what we have is a header, sidebar, content area, and footer. Seems pretty straightforward. But as I look at the HTML, the structure is so odd. Here is how this page is arranged:

```
<body>
    <div class="learndash-wrapper">
        <div class="ld-focus">  

        <!-- notice how it is starting out with sidebar even though we have 2 headers on top of each other... -->

            <div class="ld-focus-sidebar">     
                <div class="ld-focus-sidebar-wrapper">
                    <div class="ld-course-navigation">
                    Here is sidebar navigation content
                    </div> <!--/.ld-course-navigation-->
                </div> <!--/.ld-focus-sidebar-wrapper-->
            </div> <!--/.ld-focus-sidebar-->

            <!-- ok now the main content -->
            <div class="ld-focus-main">

               <!-- oh but wait, let's add header first! And namely the 2nd header! -->
               <div class="ld-focus-header">
               Here is the 2nd header
               </div> <!--/.ld-focus-header-->


               <!-- ok now that we added 2nd header, let's add main content! -->
               <div class="ld-focus-content">
               here is main content
               </div> <!--/.ld-focus-content-->

            </div> <!--/.ld-focus-main-->

        </div> <!--/.ld-focus-->
    <!--/.ld-learndash-wrapper-->


    <!-- Oh wait, now that we are at end, let's add that first header now! -->
    <div id="wpadminbar" class="">   
    The topmost header
    </div>      

</body>
```

You see what I mean? I am not a web design expert, but I tend to believe that layout of pages generally should follow similar principles to the document publishing world. That is, if your page starts with  header, probably good idea for that to be the first design element that you add, and not the last, and moreover, that the design element, if possible, should be placed in the design environment in a way that has physical correspondence to the rendered document.

I am trying to add a right sidebar to make it a 3 column layout. I tried adding a wrapper div to `<div class="ld-focus-main">` with `display: flex` and followed some of the approaches here:

http://geniuscarrier.com/2-columns-layout-with-flexbox/

```
<div class="ld-focus-main">
    <div class="ld-focus-header">

    </div> <!--/.ld-focus-header-->

    <div class="mywrapper">
        <div class="ld-focus-content">
           here is main content
        </div> <!--/.ld-focus-content-->

        <div class="mysidebar">My sidebar</div>
    </div>
</div> <!--/.ld-focus-main-->
```

Here I used (as inline styles)

```
.mywrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.ld-focus-content {
    flex-grow:1
}
```

I didn't use properties on the right sidebar since in the example in the link above it suggested that if all is well with wrapper and left then right part will follow suit.

But above doesn't produce desired result. At bottom of page linked above you see my added divs and "My Sidebar". I think part of the problem is that the theme template uses such bizarre placement of divs and properties such that when I try to add that right column the underlying structure is not making it work as expected. Sort of like 2nd, 3rd order effects... as well as a Jenga game within a Jenga game.

I was thinking about just redoing the entire template, but at this point I would prefer to just add a sticky right sidebar without a ton of rework. That said, to me it seems the proper way to do such a layout, syntactically would be

```
<div class="mainwrapper">
    <div class = "firstheader"></div>
    <div class = "secondheader"></div>
    <div class = "outercontentwrapper"></div>
        <div class = "leftnavigation"></div>
         <div class = "contentwrapper">
            <div class = "maincontent"></div>
            <div class = "rightsidebar"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "footer"></div>
</div>
```

Just not sure all the specific properties such that the page would behave as is now, plus add a right sidebar.

So with all that, how would you go about adding that right column?

Thanks!

Brian

Comment: I thought content wrapper would be needed for me to treat the content and right sidebar column as a collective. The left sidebar is so strangely specified with its properties that I thought maybe would be best to do the 2 column flex within what I showed as ```<div class="mywrapper">```. The content wrapper is what I wrote as an envisioned way to do this but I am currently trying to modify the page as is and just get the content area to be a content column and sidebar column.

Comment: Sort of have it working now, where I used this approach:https://dev.to/drews256/ridiculously-easy-row-and-column-layouts-with-flexbox-1k01 Now just need to specify smaller width for sidebar.